# Use object's method in a jstl page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a model with this method:

```
public List<String> getPriviledgeNames()
```

I'm trying to display a list of checkbox in my jstl page, and I'd like to checked only the ones which their name is in the list returned from my model.
So I have something like:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name ="priviledge" id="CheckBox2" class="checkbox" value="clickthrough" />
    <label for="CheckBox2">Clickthrough</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name ="priviledge" id="CheckBox3" class="checkbox" value="details" />
    <label for="CheckBox3">Details</label>
</li>
```

I'd like to add the checked="checked" only their name is in the list provided by my model's method. Is there a way to do this WITHOUT using scriptlet? I'd like to have no java code inside my pages...

Thanks for any helps!
Roberto

Comment: what i think you want is definitely achievable, but i m confused about the question - what is the 'their' that you refer to in `I'd like to add the checked="checked" only their name is in the list provided by my model's method.` ?

Comment: Sorry I meant only if their value is in the list, like "clickthrough" or "details"!

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:when test = "${fn:contains(list,value)}">
```

-according to the docs it's actually doing a string/string comparison, so I assume it's actually checking whether the string value is a substring of list.toString().

You could also do a manual test on each value in the list with a forEach tag but that would be messier.

Comment: yes the for loop will be a mess, I'll definitely try this solution. I didn't try because I didn't think about the toString() method to be called.

Answer (score 0):

By using a map instead of a list could do something like this:

```
 <c:if test="${yourModel.priviledgeNames['clickthrough'] ne null}">
checked="checked"</c:if>
```

Or just this: `${yourModel.priviledgeNames['clickthrough']}` by mapping your checkbox name to *checked="checked"*